# How can i pass image array to JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I Need to pass image array to JSONObject. like

```
JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject();
jObj.put("Name",image);
```

Here in place of image,can we pass an object/Array of image ? i.e can we pass an image through JSONObject ?

Comment: How is an "image" to be converted to [JSON](http://json.org) (which is only text)? What *type* of object is `image`? JSON *only* supports JSON Objects (not to be confused with Java objects), Arrays, Strings, Numbers, Booleans and Null directly.

Comment: ^^ If `image` actually is an object that encapsulates a bitmap of some sort, your code as posted is not going to work because the crufty old `org.json` stuff doesn't do any sort of serialization (and even if it did, you're not going to get anything usable). What is `image` ?

Comment: here image is an object of array that contains images.

Comment: @TarunChaudhary So, then .. How is an "image" to be converted to JSON (which is only text)? Generally one only sends URIs to images in JSON for client consumption (either for web-browser display or to fetch with additional HTTP requests) - if the actual image data is needed directly then a scheme for consuming the data will need to be established which will also drive how the conversion takes place. Base64 encoding the data is one possible mechanism but there are many subtle details (and issues with handling really big JSON documents).

Comment: @TarunChaudhary Also note that instead of sending the raw image data directly (i.e. raw pixel dump), it may be advisable to send the image data *encoded as* JPEG or PNG (i.e. as it's stored on-disk) which are portable image formats (making the JSON schema more likely to be maintainable) and support compression (to help combat the Base64/string encoding efficiency loss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to pass an array of images? In that case it would be

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(image1);
array.put(image2);

JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
jobj.put("images", array);
```